# Apex Test Coverage for Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have lots of Apex methods in a class which take an input parameter which is passed as bind variable to a dynamic SOQL.

```
List<Object__c> =
[SELECT Name,Column__c,Column2__c FROM Object__c WHERE Column3__C = :bind_variable];
```

Methods have try catch blocks. Catch blocks are catching generic Exception.
In test classes i am unable to cover lines in catch block.
What value i can pass for bind variable so that i get some exception while executing SOQL.

Comment: If you have no explicit reason to have the try/catch blocks then removing them may be the best solution. Generally catching exceptions does more harm than good.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

1. Your query is returning Object__c and your List is of type Column3__C. I am sure its a typing mistake.
2. I don't think this SOQL query can have any exception, alternatively you can manually throw an exception in the method, something like this for one record..

   ```
   if(Test.isRunningTest() && record[0].Name == 'FlagRecordForCatchBlock') {      throw new Exception('Just to cover catch block');
    }
   ```

This should go to your catch block.

Comment: i would prefer a way to achieve this without changing the method being covered.

Comment: One other way I could think of is - create 50K+ test records and try to fetch all of them in single query. `System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001` should be returned!

Comment: @SantanuHalder Except there's a 10k DML row limit...

Comment: Oh right! I am out then can't think of anything else!

Answer (score 1):

- Its correct that you should write a code/conditions in test class in such a way which will cause an exception in try block and cover your Catch block code

--> and the **Best Practice is to do so only.**

I also faced this situations lots of time - But there is another way out (you can say shortcut without caring about the coding standards-ANYWAY it doesn't cause any issue/problem -NEVER) -

> Simply Write your "Catch Block" in one line(Only one line - remove all
>   Enter's/Page breaks in code), just like

```
}catch(){ My First Line; My Second Line;}
```